Tryting to export data from one table but got error
I'm new to database export/import stuffs (as I'm not DBA), and I'm recently tasked to develop a housekeeping script which include the export data pump (expdp) subtask.
But for some reasons, when I run expdp command and check the log file, it sometimes shows me this error.
ORA-31693: Table data object "<schema>"."<table_name>":"<SYS_P...sth>" failed to load/unload and is being skipped due to error:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

And sometimes it shows this kind of log (it can export but somehow it exports 0 rows with a little memory space)
. . exported "<schema>"."<table_name>":"<SYS_P...sth>"     .. KB 0 rows

Can anyone help me what caused the problem, or where should I take a look in the command?
Note that the table and data exist in the database (same schema that I use to query the data normally) as I can query and check the data and row count.

Update: I removed the QUERY param and it works, so I'm currently think that sth is wrong with QUERY (it only occurs when I do subquery to get a list of ID from another table)

Ok, finally I know what happened. Since the data pumping schema is different from the main schema, I need to specify the schema in the subquery, or it cannot see the table/data object in the subquery.
It's under my nose all along!
